# How would I print out any number x times as a list in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, printing

If, for example, I want to print the number `5`, ten times...and then create a list from this, i.e.:

```
list = [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: That code solves your stated question.  Do you mean you want a _shorter_ way to do it?

Comment: I'd like to generate it for n numbers, so if I said I wanted it printed a billion times...I think I have it tho!

Answer (score 3):

```
In [39]: [5]*10
Out[39]: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the list multiplier (as the Vishnu Upadhyay answer) which will generate the whole list (take care with the **memory** when handling **huge lists**) :

```
[number] * times
```

Or you can use *itertools.repeat* to generate a generator:

```
import itertools
gen_list = itertools.repeat(number, times)
# to print it resolve the generator
print(list(gen_list))
```

More information about *repeat* can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat).

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
list = [5]*n
```

maybe just add `try` in case someone entered non-integer

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy, can use following steps:

```
import numpy as np
np.ones(10)*5
```